# Elements from collection get truncated when printing - Smalltalk

Tags: loops, collections, nested, smalltalk, pharo

I am extremely new to Smalltalk, so please excuse me if I am implementing this solution incorrectly.

I'm reading a table from a txt file that looks like this:

```
1 3 5
2 4 7
55 30 50
```

I am reading the file through an readStream as follows:

```
inStream := inFile readStream.
```

where `inFile` is the address of the input file.

`inStream` gets used to build the table with this method:

```
readInput: inStream
        
        | line |
        
        rows := OrderedCollection new.
        [ (line := inStream nextLine) notNil ] whileTrue: [ rows add: line.
                                                            Transcript 
                                                                        show: 'read line:';
                                                                        show: line;
                                                                        cr.
                                                          ].
```

Finally, I'm printing specific columns with this method:

```
printCols: columns
    "comment stating purpose of instance-side method"
    "scope: class-variables  &  instance-variables"
    
    | columnsCollection |
    
    columnsCollection := columns findTokens: ','.

    rows do: [ :currentRow |
                            columnsCollection do: [ :each |
                                                            Transcript 
                                                                    show: (currentRow at: (each asInteger) );
                                                                    show: ' '.                                                                                          
                                                  ].
                            Transcript cr.
              ].
```

where `columns` is a comma separated list of columns I'm interested in printing passed in as a string.

I'm not sure what's wrong in my `printCols` function, but the output I'm seeing always removes the second number of a given item. For example, when printing column 1, I'll get:

```
1
2
5
```

any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here is the reason: `currentRow` is a `String`, isn't it? Then `currentRow at: each asInteger` is a `Character`, in fact the `each`th character of `currentRow`. BTW, since `each` is already an `Integer` you don't need to send it `asInteger`.

Comment: Thank you @LeandroCaniglia ! You are exactly right! I'm going to post  below how I solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Leandro Caniglia mentions in the comments of the post, the problem is that `currentRow` is a String, while I was expecting it to be a collection, and therefore, in the `columnsCollection` loop, I'm accessing a single character instead of an element from the collection.

The solution was to change how I'm reading in the rows to make sure they are taken as a collection of collections instead of a collection of Strings.

```
readInput: inStream

        | line |
        
        rows := OrderedCollection new.
        [ (line := inStream nextLine) notNil ] whileTrue: [ |row|
                                                                row := OrderedCollection new.
                                                                row := line findTokens: ' '.
                                                                rows add: row.
                                                          ].
```

Thanks for the help!